# Confusing events name while listening to observer

Tags: magento-1.7, event-observer

I am working on site where i have to listen for the matching events and run code according to that event.when print the code in observer

`print_r($observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getFullActionName());`.
I got the events name like `( customer_account_loginPost,customer_account_login,catalog_category_view,checkout_cart_add)`.
But when i check the event list (on different webistes like [magentocommerce](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/events),[nickysys](http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-7/) ) for the events name they are different like`(customer_login,add_to_cart_before etc)` and also my captured events name are not there

. How can i map these events with each other.I am confuse about the events names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not outputting the event names with `print_r($observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getFullActionName());`

You are outputting the ACTION NAMES, in controllers, that the event is from.

for example: customer_account_loginPost is module customer, controller account, and method loginPost in that controller.

To get the list of events that get run during a page load, edit app/mage.php and in the method dispatchEvent echo out the $name variable.

Comment: But i want to get event name in observer.How can do that ?

Comment: Why would you need to do that? You are already in the event, thus why would you need the name of the event? The only reason I can phantom you are needing this is that you are using the same method for all your events? Anyways - the event name can be found using the call $observer->getEvent()->getName()

Comment: GetName shows current event name.I want to listen for the events in my observer .Like if someone click on add to cart then i got add_to_cat event.I want to do it in my observer.Hopes you got my point.

Comment: Ok, You are misunderstanding how the events work / what they are. 
Please read this: http://www.solvingmagento.com/events-and-observers-a-magento-tutorial/